redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
I am working on a stock market app. where i am pushing all the callback from order subscription to redis queue and then executing further action based on the order executed.
    for OrderQId in scriptSeries.OrderQId:
        if OrderQId is not None:
            mq = MessageQueue(OrderQId)
            mq.clearQueue() 

using a custom lass call MessageQueue where i have implemented all redis method.
class MessageQueue():
    def __init__(self, QueueId):    
        self.QueueId = QueueId
        self.Redis = StrictRedis()
        # self.Redis = StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db=settings.REDIS_DB, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)



when clearing the queue by poping out element, it throws "redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"
sharing the current situation of the keys and tried passing binary value with encoding utf as well without any luck. also tried with redis and stricredis
the same code is working in my .ipynb code on the same system.
also below code from redis.io works fine.
res1 = r.lpush("bikes:repairs", "bike:1")
print(res1)  # >>> 1

res2 = r.lpush("bikes:repairs", "bike:2")
print(res2)  # >>> 2

res3 = r.rpop("bikes:repairs")
print(res3)  # >>> bike:1

res4 = r.rpop("bikes:repairs")
print(res4)  # >>> bike:2

Not sure what wrong i am doing.
